# Spring boot REST API returns partial response

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have an Spring boot REST API that returns around 1GB of JSON output. However, the application stops returning results after 5mins.

I had already set the timeout values in different iterations with no success.

```
server:
  connection-timeout: 50000000
  session:
    timeout: 1000000
  servlet:
    session:
      timeout: 1000s
```

I have also set the timeout in the rest template to 10 mins and the API returns partial response with rest template and results in JSON parse error.

Spring boot version : 2.2.0.RELEASE

I looked at the other stack overflow answers. None of them seem to be working.

I had also tried in curl and it stops with the error

```
curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
```

In Spring boot, it results in unable to parse the JSON response error as the response was not complete.

Comment: Sorry, this comment is not strictly related to your question, but can you elaborate more on what you want to do with such a JSON? Preparing 1 GB JSON in memory is crazy even for the server, Also note that JSON has to be fully prepared from some objects that also probably reside in memory on a server... Then even if you'll succeed, what kind of client will be able to parse such a huge JSON? On the browser, you probably also won't be able to show it... So what's the use case?

Comment: the clients will take the response, save it in a file and process it in spark. The clients have processed 10 GB of txt files in spark.

Comment: I see, thanks, is there any option to read CSV for example? this way you could prepare it on server line by line and start sending back to client before the whole object is even ready? As for your error, usually curl raises this error if the content length of the returned object is calculated wrong on server. See: https://bobcares.com/blog/curl-18-transfer-closed-with-outstanding-read-data-remaining/

Comment: I saw that options. I am not sure how to set the correct Content Length. Will it also result in partial response as well? The problem is that rest client and the curl currently stops after 5 mins.

Comment: That's the point, the json has to be prepared in memory before it can be sent to the client. With CSV it's not the case. you can gradually send data to client. See for example https://www.logicbig.com/how-to/code-snippets/jcode-spring-mvc-streamingresponsebody.html  Is that an acceptable solution produce wise in your case?

Comment: Inline with above comments you should ask for data in multiple iterations, the ideal way to handle this scenario can be that you pass the offset and sensible size of bytes which you need in every iteration and at client side you keep on appending bytes you received it in your file.